# Azure durable function with Service Bus

Tags: c#, function, azure, azureservicebus

Our current Azure function on consumption plan works all ok, but a couple of  third party apis are pushing us above 10 mins limit.

We are considering using durable functions to make it cleaner and push these apis to its own activity functions. However, the bigger issue is we get triggered by service bus message.

Now how do we push the message back in the queue from the orchestrator if there's any error so that it can be retried? Has anyone faced anything similar?

Thanks

Comment: I can't tell in the context of Azure functions/durable functions, but in regards of ASB, if you do not explicitly 'complete/abandon/deadletter' the message in the client side (because there is an error in the flow without handling, or because the lock timeout expired), the message will popup back in the Topic you read it from, being available to another consumers after the "lock duration" period, and will do this a total of "Max Delivery Count" times before automatically deadlettering the message.

Comment: Like Salas mentioned if there is error (you don't have error handling in place e.g. exception is thrown ) in the flow the message is added back to the subscription to be picked up again until eventually it ends up in dead letter queue after retries count reached max. if you have exception handling then service bus will consider it completed unless you explicitly set the staus to abandon

Comment: In the context of durable functions, the triggered function grabs the message in peek mode. Once the orchestrator's scheduled, if nothing is remaining to be done in that function effectively, the message is marked complete. The orchestrator does all the interesting bits which is where the apis get called and potential issues might rise where the message can be thrown back (which has been already marked as successful).